# Variadic Function Universal Sentinel Value

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a variadic function that takes an unknown number of arguments and creates an array of the input type (Its a template function so if the input arguments are floats, it returns a float ptr and likewise for other data types)

I was thinking that I can use either `NAN` or `INFINITY` as a sentinel value because one of them theoretically would never be used in an array (at least for my purposes).

More or less the function looks like this

```
template<typename T>
T* arrayIt(T first, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, first);

    T n = first, *array = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));
    int sz = 0;
    while(!(isnan(n)) /* or infinite(n) */){
        sz++; // inc array size
        array = realloc(array, sizeof(T)*(sz+1)); // realloc

        array[sz] = n;
        n = va_arg(ap, T); // update temp 
    }

    array[0] = sz; // store size of array

    return (array + 1); //doing this places the first element at array[0]
    // the size of the array is stored at array[-1] 
}
```

The function works as planned with everything except ints.
I would like to know how to use the function this way using `NAN` as a sentinal.
I would also like to do this preferably without a macro.

i.e. `int * a = arrayIt<int>(1,2,3,4,5,6,NAN);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not answer the exact question you're asking, but in C++11, you can just do this:

```
template <typename T, typename... Vals>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Vals)> arrayIt(Vals... vals) {
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(Vals)>{static_cast<T>(vals)... };
}
```

To be used without a sentinel, like:

```
auto a = arrayIt<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. I've been stuck in the last c++ release and haven't taken the time to learn the new things. I'll try it out when I get a chance!